# Can't start mysql with kernel error

Tags: kernel, mysql

I'm trying start mysql but this not working.I'm open syslog and see this error.

```
May 22 08:40:28 blacker-ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community 
Server...
May 22 08:40:28 blacker-ubuntu kernel: [ 3175.104982] audit: type=1400 audit(1495417228.964:347): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/18181/status" pid=18181 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=124 ouid=124
May 22 08:40:28 blacker-ubuntu kernel: [ 3175.104995] audit: type=1400 audit(1495417228.964:348): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=18181 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=124 ouid=0
May 22 08:40:28 blacker-ubuntu kernel: [ 3175.105030] audit: type=1400 audit(1495417228.964:349): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/18181/status" pid=18181 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=124 ouid=124
May 22 08:40:29 blacker-ubuntu systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 22 08:40:43 blacker-ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
May 22 08:40:43 blacker-ubuntu systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 22 08:40:43 blacker-ubuntu systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

- Mysql version 5.7.18-0ubuntu0.17.04.1
- Ubuntu Gnome 17.04

Comment: What is the background to getting to this point?

Comment: This is a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.7/+bug/1610765)

Comment: @Xaqron Yes.i readed this bug but everything is normal yesterday

Comment: @George sorry.i'm updated my question

Comment: i'm remove mysql-* and reinstall.Mysql started and working.Thanks.